# Force ubuntu key password manager to forget incorrect password for github credentials

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I'm trying to push an existing git repository to github.

In my repo's local directory, I enter:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:mittenchops/distributed-demo.git
git push -u origin master
```

An ubuntu dialog pops up asking me for the password to unlock this key.  The keychain usually keeps track of this for me, so I don't remember the password for my key that often except when adding totally new repos, and as such, I probably typed it incorrectly.

So, I get the following error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:mittenchops/distributed-demo.git'
```

However, when I try again to push, with the correct password in mind, the dialog doesn't pop up again---it seems to try again using the incorrect one I had previously typed.  I have to completely reboot to get the enter-password dialog.  How can I force the key manager to allow me to re-enter  my password without rebooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I had misdiagnosed.  I had in fact entered the right credentials.  The problem is I had never /committed/ in my local git repository, so it didn't see any files, and when I went to push, it had no commits to push.

So, simply adding:

```
git commit -A
```

(write your commit message)

```
git push -u origin master
```

solves everything, but I do wish the git error message had said something more clear, like "sorry, there are no commits to push."